# InteliJ generate a setter for each element of the array instead for the whole array

Tags: java, arrays, intellij-idea

I have a class

```
Class HighScores{
    private int[] scores = new int[10];

    void setScores(int[] in){
        this.scores = in;
    }
}
```

But what i want to be able to do is be able to set each element of the array to it's own getter. Can InteliJ generate the getters? Or would i have to write it out by hand like this?

```
  Class HighScores{
        private int[] scores = new int[10];

        void setScores(int inZero){
            this.scores[0] = inZero;
        }

         void setScoresZero(int inZero){
            this.scores[0] = inZero;
         }
         void setScoresOne(int inOne){
            this.scores[1] = inOne;
         }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: How about having two arguments, first index and second value?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you use the [Arrays.fills()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill-int:A-int-) then you can get a very similar approach:

```
void setScoresToValue(int value) {
    Arrays.fill(this.scores, value);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(this.scores));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
    sc.setScoresToValue(255);
}
```

so if you want so set the array to zero the call

```
 sc.setScoresToValue(0);
```

## Edit:

if you are looking for a way to set the value at any given index in the array then consider defining a method where you can pass the index and the new value...

## Example:

```
   void setScoresAtIndex(int index, int value) {
//  you can either validate the index or let it throw the IndexOutOfBoundsException
    this.scores[index] = value;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(this.scores));
    }
```

Comment: The OP asked about setting values individually, not setting all of the values at once.

Comment: @bradimus , thnxs for the comment... I think now is the answer up to date... take a look and let me know....